# WP cron: when to schedule a 1-time event

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-cron

I have a custom post type ('my_cpt') and upon `save_post_my_cpt` I need to possibly make a large number of modifications to other posts (depending on the state of the post, e.g., post_status, post_meta values and terms from custom taxonomy).  These other modifications might need to be made in other blogs in a multisite.  Hence, the function called on `save_post_my_cpt` might take up to a minute or so to complete execution...which isn't very "user friendly" for the admin user doing the content changes.

I'm setting things up so that these other modifications happen via WP Cron.  So I have:

```
add_action ('save_post_my_cpt', 'save_cpt') ;

function
save_cpt ($post_id)
{
    if (defined ('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return ;
        }

    // do stuff related to saving post meta, etc
    // e.g., update_post_meta ($post_id, '_some_meta_name', $_REQUEST['some_meta_name'], true) ;

    // schedule an event to do the modifications of other posts
    // see below for question related to the time this cron job will be scheduled
    $time = time () ;
    wp_schedule_single_event ($time, 'my_cron_hook', array ($post_id)) ;

    return ;
}

add_action ('my_cron_hook', 'cron_func') ;

function
cron_func ($post_id)
{
    $post = get_post ($post_id) ;

    // get_blogs_that_might_need_to_be_modified() returns an array of blog_id's that
    // MIGHT have other posts related to $post that need to be modified

    // get_posts_in_that_blog_that_need_to_be_modified() returns an array of posts
    // related to $post that need to be modified

    // modify_post() returns a modified version of a related post based on the
    // current state of $post

    // the details of these functions aren't relevant to this question
    foreach (get_blogs_that_might_need_to_be_modified ($post) as $blog_id) {
        switch_to_blog ($blog_id) ;

        foreach (get_posts_in_that_blog_that_need_to_be_modified ($post) as $other_post) {
            $other_post = modify_post ($post) ;
            wp_update_post ($other_post) ;
            }

        restore_current_blog () ;
        }
}
```

Hopefully, everyone is with me up to this point.  My question has to do with the time at which I should schedule this 1 time cron job.

If I schedule the cron job to run "immediately" (as in the code above), can I be assured that by the time `cron_func()` is called that ALL of the DB updates related to the saving of my CPT will have completed (since the funcs called in `cron_func()` will need to read the modified state of `$post_id`)?

Scheduling the event to run "immediately" seems to work fine in my local development environment (where I'm the only one hitting the site).

I'm wondering if I'll likely have any problems doing things this way when the site is running in a heavy activity production environment (i.e., with a number of admin users simultanously editing content on the back end, while a fair number of end-users are hitting the front end)

Two alternatives I'm considering:

1. add some offset to `time()` when scheduling the event?

   1. e.g., schedule it to run 1 minute later
   2. if I need to do this, any guesses as to how long I should wait
2. gather all of the info I need in `save_cpt()` and pass it in the `$args` param to `wp_schedule_single_event()`

   1. I would prefer not to go this route, as gathering that info could itself take a while, which would slow things down for the admin user
   2. is there "expense" (i.e., memory/etc) in passing a large amount of info to a job via cron?

Are there any other considerations that I should be accounting for?  For example, what is likely the happen when:

1. admin user A edits post X, which schedules the cron job
2. before that cron job finishes, admin user B makes another edit to post X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I schedule the cron job to run "immediately" (as in the code
>   above), can I be assured that by the time  cron_func() is called that
>   ALL of the DB updates related to the saving of my CPT will have
>   completed (since the funcs called in cron_func() will need to read the
>   modified state of $post_id)

Yes. `save_post` hook is fired after the post has been actually saved. So, the `cron_func` will get the modified state of the post. You don't need any alternative for this.

> Are there any other considerations that I should be accounting for?
>   For example, what is likely the happen when:
>
> 1. admin user A edits post X, which schedules the cron job before that
>      cron job finishes,
> 2. admin user B makes another edit to post X

If the cron job take some time, it's very possible to encounter such an issue. To solve this issue, you might raise a flag(it can be a post meta) when creating the cron task and clear the flag when cron task finishes. You might want to disable editing of the post as long as the flag is present for a post.

Comment: thanx. On the 1st point: I know that `do_action ("save_post_{$post->post_type}")` is done at the very end of `wp_insert_post()`.   I guess my question is: are the `$wpdb` operations "blocking", that is, could `$wpdb->update()` possibly return before the db server (which is a different machine than WP is running on) actually writes the updated data to disc?  Note: I have **complete** control over **all** of the plugin/theme code used on this site, so I can ensure that my `save_cpt()` func is the only that will fire on edits to this CPT.

Comment: I haven't seen any code for asynchronous operation in `$wpdb` or Wordpress in general. So `$wpdb->update()`  will wait before it gets response from server. The only issue I can think of is DB server response is too late and php execution time expires which means that the cron task do not get fired. But that is a server optimization problem rather than a wordpress one.

Comment: On the 2nd point: that's probably a good idea. I just hacked up something to use the `_edit_lock` post_meta that WP core sets when a post is being edited (to simulate that the administrator user has acquired the lock).  This kinda-sorta works, but will need some more research/testing to make sure.

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron There are lots of hook in edit page section. You can use those to take appropriate action based on your need.

Comment: I just did some poking around into the source for [wpdb::_do_query()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1871), which calls [PHP: mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and,yes, everything does appear to be synchronous.  I'll talk to my DBA to make sure there is nothing on the db server-side which could mess this up.

Comment: I'll leave your answer "unaccepted" for a few days to see if anyone else chimes in with contrary answers, but will most likely be accepting it then. Thanx for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. I wish you all the best.